# Pandas: Creating New Column for Previous Week Values with Multiple IDs

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm working with time series data. I need to find the previous week values for each entry. My data has 3 columns: ID, Date, and Value. I wanted to create a 4th column for LWValue (Last Week's Value). Here what the sample data might look like:

```
    ID  Date  Value  
0    1  2/1/2020     100       
1    2  2/1/2020     80      
2    1  2/2/2020     105       
3    2  2/2/2020     84       
4    1  2/8/2020     102       
5    2  2/8/2020    82       
6    1  2/9/2020    104       
7    2  2/9/2020     86
```

[Sample Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94UyK.jpg)

How would I go about doing this in Pandas?

I tried this:

```
# create new column
df["LWValues"] = pd.Series()  

# test out code on same values
df.loc[((df.ID == df.ID) & (df.Date == (df.Date) )), "LWValues"].values

# test out code with timedelta grabbing last week
df.loc[((df.ID == df.ID) & (df.Date == (df.Date - datetime.timedelta(days=7)) )), "LWValues"].values
```

When I do that, the 2nd operation works, but the final one, trying to pull data from the previous week with the timedelta argument does not. Instead, I get an empty array.

How do I need to fix this code?

Alternatively, is there a better way to get the previous week data in Pandas than this?

Comment: please add your sample data as text

Answer (score 0):

df.loc doesn't work that way. In your case, it just comparing each row with itself. One way to do this is by using apply.

```
df.apply(lambda row : df.loc[(df.ID == row['ID']) & (df.Date == (row['Date'] - datetime.timedelta(days=7)))]['Value'], axis=1)
```

Don't forget to handle the case where there's no last week entry for a row.